# typeorm me devuelve undefined al buscar un usuario

Tags: mongodb, passport, typeorm

estoy utilizando passport para descifrar el token desde el headers pero me encuentro con un error, esta es mi `strategy` de passport

```
const strategy =  new Strategy(opts, async (payload: any, done: VerifiedCallback) => {
  try {
    const user: Usuario | undefined = await Usuario.findOne(payload.id);
    if (user) return done(null, user);
    return done(null, null);
  } catch (error) {
    throw new HandlePassportError(error);
  }
});
```

estoy utilizando `typeorm` para hacer las consultas, el problema es que nunca encuentra el usuario, ni siquiera me trae todos con un simple `Usuario.find()` no se que es lo que pasa, ayuda

Comment: ¿No te saltan advertencias con ese `payload: any`? Ya que luego pretendes usar `payload.id`. Por otro lado, dices que no te trae nada con una consulta `find()`. ¿Has verificado que estás conectado a la base de datos correcta y que la misma tenga datos realmente? Saludos.

Comment: prueba a hacer debug en tu código y ver que es lo que te está llegando a la línea donde haces el `Usuario.findOne`